# How do I pause my batch script without having to add a pause command?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-explorer, batch

Sometimes I need to do certain Windows tasks as TrustedInstaller like copying, deleting, renaming, moving files/folders, etc. So I created this batch script that kills Explorer.exe and launches Total Commander as TrustedInstaller using PowerRun.

I would like the script to launch Total Commander (and I do whatever tasks I need to do) then when I close Total Commander, Explorer.exe automatically starts without the need to add a pause in the script.

I tried with "start "" /wait" and "call" but I cannot make them work with PowerRun.

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im explorer*
"%~dp0PowerRun_x64.exe" /SW:0 "TOTALCMD64.EXE" 
pause 
start "" explorer.exe
exit
```

Comment: Answered here: [windows - How do you wait for an exe to complete in batch file? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/245393/how-do-you-wait-for-an-exe-to-complete-in-batch-file/730833). See the answers using `tasklist ` in a `for` loop

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative without using a for loop and using only one label

```bat
@echo off

>nul 2>&1 %__APPDIR__%Net.exe file || goto :Elevate

SetLocal EnableExtensions & Set "_EXE=TOTALCMD64.EXE"
Set "_KEY="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoRestartShell /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"

Reg Add %_KEY%
Taskkill /f /im explorer*
"%~dp0PowerRun_x64.exe" /SW:0 "%_EXE%"

:LOOP
Timeout /nobreak 03 
Tasklist | find /i "%_EXE%" >nul && goto LOOP

Reg Add %_KEY:0=1%
Start "" /b explorer.exe 
endlocal & goto eof 

:Elevate
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
For %%i in (%*)do Set "_Args=!_Args! "%%~i""

Set "_cmd_Args= /x/d/q/c "%~0" !_Args!"
Set "_ps1=%__APPDIR__%\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe"
%_ps1% -nop -c start $env:windir\system32\cmd.exe -Arg $env:_cmd_Args -v runas
endlocal & exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks @It Wasn't Me it works except I get this "ERROR: Invalid syntax."

Comment: Ops... odd `"` in: `set "_KEY=<   "   >HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" .... "`

Comment: Super @lo-ol it was now showing ERROR: "Access is denied." so I had to elevate the script to modify the Registry with this line

`@reg query HKU\S-1-5-19>nul 2>nul||(set 0="%~f0" %*&powershell -nop -c start cmd -args '/x/d/q/rcall',$env:0 -v runas&exit)`

Comment: Didn't work in Windows 11. Explorer wouldn't restart

Comment: try using the same line:  `Reg Add %_KEY:0=1% & Start "" /b explorer.exe`

Comment: maybe `start "" ...`  without `/b`

Comment: Explorer still doesn't restart in a non Admin account in Windows 11 thanks. I finally got one that works in both Windows 10 and 11. I added it to my Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final working script all cleaned up and working in both Windows 10 and 11

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=TOTALCMD64.EXE
taskkill /f /im explorer*
"%~dp0PowerRun_x64.exe" /SW:0 "%EXE%"
:LOOP
timeout /t 3 /nobreak
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto LOOP
start "" explorer.exe
endlocal &exit
```